# IndexOutOfBounds when executing a NamedQuery twice

Tags: servlets, ejb, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to make a web application for the first time, and I use all kinds of tutorials and help of any kind, but I don't get why this happens. Everything worked all right until now:

I'm trying to transmit a "User" attribute between servlets, and I'm doing so by sending part of it as an attribute (using RequestDispatcher or HTML forms), and looking up the rest of it in a database, like this:

```
String user = (String) request.getAttribute("txt");
Users info = (Users) emf.createEntityManager().createNamedQuery("Users.findByUsername").setParameter("username",user).getResultList().get(0);
```

Username is Unique key, and the code for the NamedQuery is

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Users.findByUsername", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.username = :username)
```

The first time I use this, it works and I get the expected result, but, if I come back to the same servlet or I use the same code again in other servlet, I get `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsExpcetion: Index: 0, Size: 0`

How can this happen if I didn't modify the database at any moment?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your request attribute "txt" is null the second time. It's a request attribute, so it will be only valid during the request. If you don't store it or submit it every time it will be null.

A null as username will produce an empty list. The attempt to read the first element of an empty list produces the IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Use a session attribute or resubmit the attribute every time and it will work.